# Increasing multiple values in dictionary inside Firestore document

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firestore document that contains a dictionary like the following:

statAggregation{games: 10, stat1: 1, stat2: 3, stat3: 7, stat4: 15, stat5: 0, stat6: 12}

This document contains the aggregated stats of all game documents, each game document contains the totals for stats 1-6. Every time a new game is created I want to add 1 to the games and increment by the individual stat values in that game. I know I can increment each value in the dictionary when a new game is created, by using the games.increment() or stat1.increment() method, but as I understood it that would be 7 write operations (1 to update game count and 6 to update each stat). I was thinking it may be more cost effective to actually read the current stat aggregation document, update on the client, and then write it back. That way it would just be 1 read to get the document and 1 write to put the updated document back. I was just wondering which would be better from a design/cost perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update as many fields as you like in a single call to `updateData()`, and it will only count as a single write.  The update can have as many uses of `FieldValue.increment()` as you want - it does not change the cost or performance.  In this particular case, reading then writing the document doesn't give any particular benefits.